# Converting key value rdd to just a rdd with list of values

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

How can I convert a key value rdd, to a rdd with just a list of values in PySpark?

Suppose the rdd has (key1, “this is a test”) and (key2, “today is Sunday), I want to transform this rdd into a rdd which has (“this is a test”, “today is Sunday”)

The key value pair is the user_id and tweets, and I want to tokenize the tweets first, and report the count per token. Followed by doing the same for particular group of users. All in PySpark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is [`values`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html?highlight=values#pyspark.RDD.values)

Regarding the other steps, please post a sample of the data and the desired output.

```
> rdd = sc.parallelize([("key1", "this is a test"), ("key2", "today is Sunday")])
> print rdd.values().collect()
```

> ['this is a test', 'today is Sunday']